# Rails 4: Parsing large csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, resque

I have a very large csv file that I need to read, parse, and then present the user with the data so they can make adjustments / verify that things look correct.

The process works locally, but when deployed to Heroku, I run into a `Request Timeout` error because the parsing takes too long.

```
2017-07-27T13:47:25.399387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"
```

I understand that I should use something like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), and I've used it for emails, but I do not understand how to use it, if I need to do additional processing with the returned object.

**Can someone provide an example of how to access a returned object from a Resque job?**

Here's my code, the first function is in the controller, which calls a model function, and then redirects after the model function finishes parsing (which is the process that takes so long).

```
def check_upload_file
    @response = WeighIn.check_file(params[:file], params[:location])
    @final = {}
    @file = params[:file]
    @client_names = []

    @final[:success] = @response[:successful_entry]
    @final[:name_fail] = @response[:name_error]
    @final[:weigh_fail] = @response[:weigh_in_error]
    @final[:location_id] = @response[:location_id]

    # Need to mess with this to use 'include' and see if speed improves
    @clients = Client.all.order("name ASC").select(:name)
    @clients.each { |c| @client_names << c.name unless c.name.nil? }

    render 'weigh_ins/preview'
end

def self.check_file(file, location_id)

    status = {
        name_error: [],
        weigh_in_error: [],
        successful_entry: [],
        location_id: location_id
    }

    status[:file] = file.original_filename
    options = {:key_mapping => @new_hash, :strings_as_keys => true, :keep_original_headers => true, :remove_unmapped_keys => true}

    SmarterCSV.process(file.path, options) do |row|
        hashed_row = row[0]
        hashed_row[:unique_mb] = ( location_id.to_s + hashed_row[:scale_id].to_s ).to_i
        hashed_row[:unique_scale] = ( location_id.to_s + hashed_row[:scale_id].to_s ).to_i

        # Escape missing scale ids
        next if hashed_row[:scale_id].nil?

        client = Client.find_by(unique_scale: hashed_row[:unique_scale]) || Client.find_by(unique_mb: hashed_row[:unique_mb])
        hashed_row = hashed_row.except!(:unique_mb)

        # Handle missing client
        if client.nil?
            status[:name_error] << hashed_row
            next
        end

        check_ins_with_no_weigh_ins = client.check_ins.with_no_weigh_ins
        hashed_row[:client_id] = client.id

        if check_ins_with_no_weigh_ins.length != 1
            hashed_row[:empty_check_ins] = check_ins_with_no_weigh_ins.length
            hashed_row[:check_ins] = client.check_ins.length
            status[:weigh_in_error] << hashed_row   
        else
            hashed_row[:check_in_id] = check_ins_with_no_weigh_ins.first.id
            status[:successful_entry] << hashed_row
        end

    end

    return status
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way:

- Upload the file to s3 (with Carrierwave or other), and store the path in a queue-like table or in Redis with a status 'pending'
- Process what's pending asynchronously (with Resque or a simple cron job) and save the result to s3 again (and update the state to 'processed').
- Display to the user what's processed when it's ready, you might need websockets.

Alternatively, you could dig in the Heroku configuration to see if you can adjust the duration before Timeout. I wouldn't recommend it though.